# Writing structured text documents

Tags: text-editor, ms-office, openoffice

I recently bought an Android tablet with a keyboard, and would like to use it to take notes of conferences, lectures, meetings etc. On a Windows or Linux notebook,  I would use the excellent [LyX](http://www.lyx.org) system for this. LyX basically allows you to write structured text without worrying about the layout, saying "this is a #3 heading" or "this should be emphasized" instead of "this should be bold and a larger size". LyX then allows you to export your text as PDF, DOC, ODF, LaTeX and so on.

I am looking for an App that allows a similar approach to writing for Android. What I already tested:

- [Writer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jamesmc.writer) is almost what I'm searching, a minimalist text editor that understands Markdown and saves its document as plain text on the Android device (no network necessary). I'd like a few more formatting options and an export feature, though.
- [Write:Tablet](https://market.android.com/details?id=uk.amimetic.journal.honeycomb) doesn't seem to have many structuring features
- Most "office" packages like Polaris Office do not offer format templates, but restrict the user to bold / italic / font size types of formatting
- Google Docs needs a constant net connection

So, I'm aware that this is a very small niche I am looking for here, and such an app would probably not make sense on phones, but is there another interesting tool for structured text creation?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for introducing Lyx, pretty impressive open source app.

There are two products from [Verbosus](https://www.verbosus.com/). I understood that Lyx is a Latex based tool and hence producing this link.

I am not confident enough whether suggested Latex editor will be equivalent to Lyx, but just trying to help.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at one of the following apps:

- [NoteLynX Pro Outliner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.astrodean.notelynxpro): Hierarchical organization of notes, customizable CSS, lots of formatting options, hyperlinks and more, XML export
- [Wikilin](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mosharu.wikilin): As the name suggest, a wiki-style editor. Cross-platform, different formatting options
- [Ema Personal Wiki](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.janwillemboer.ema): Another wiki-style editor with dropbox support, also a Windows version available
- [WikiMind note](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sweetrain.wikimind): Again wiki-style editor, cross-document links, macro support, encryption support

There are also several LaTeX editors on the market, but to me they looked rather complicated. From your question I take it you prefer something like wiki-style -- but feel free to offer a more detailed description of what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There are several **Markdown editors** for Android, but it's hard to compare and this are evolving. What I have found so far, includes (sorted alphabetically):

- [Draft](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mvilla.draft)
- [MarkDrop](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.keepzero.markdrop)
- [JotterPad X: Writer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jotterpad.x)
- [LightPaper Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.clockworkengine.android.LightPaper)
- [MarkDawn](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.blogspot.versionupsoft.markdawn)
- [Notal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fusionfenix.notal)
- [Writer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jamesmc.writer)
- [Write: Tablet Notepad/Journal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.amimetic.journal.honeycomb)

To find the best application for your needs, first make clear the most important features, such as Dropbox sync or support of a specific Markdown dialect - for instance information about the latter is hard to find from the official app description. For this reason I cannot recommend one app (shopping recommendations should not be given at this place anyway).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to a markdown text editor which has export capability, you should try [JotterPad X](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jotterpad.x).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Omnibus Writer, which is recently released on the amazon app store ([http://www.amazon.com/Jerry-He-Omnibus-Writer/dp/B00PA8VUIS/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00PA8VUIS)), there is a cheaper version ($0.99) on android app store, but it has banner ads on the bottom and I ended up returning it.

Not only can you use the markdown syntax, it also allows you to write math equations(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YfOnOXirIOs) in a similar way to Lyx, so you can write your Math Homework on the go.